# What does "the first, then the second, the third and the fourth" mean in Ziyarat Ashura?

Tags: shiism

It is stated in [Ziyarat Ashura](http://www.duas.org/ashura/z_ashura.htm):

> O my Allah, let the curse I call down on the head of the first tyrant stick like a leech; and stay put for ever on *the first, then the second, the third and the fourth*.

What does "the first, then the second, the third and the fourth" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ziyarat Ashura is an authentic and reputable hadith narrated from Imam Muhammad Baqir a.s. the 5th infallible Imam and one of the [Ahl al Bayt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahl_al-Bayt) who [loving](http://tanzil.net/#42:23) and [obeying](http://tanzil.net/#4:59) them is obligatory for Muslims. This hadith is narrated from 5th Imam by different reputable chain of narrators.

It is not mentioned in a any reputable hadith that who are the first, then the second, the third and the fourth in Ziyarat Ashura. In fact it is as it is. It is not defined and no one can say certainly who they mean in this hadith.

[Shaykh Tusi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaykh_Tusi) in his book Al-Istibsar (the fourth important book of Shi'a Islamic Hadith) has said that the first means the son of Adam who murdered his pious brother. The second is [Qeydar who hamstrung and murdered](http://tanzil.net/#91:14) the [Camel of God](http://tanzil.net/#91:13) and the 3th is who murdered prophet Yahya Ibn Zakariya a.s. ([John the Baptist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_the_Baptist) who is mentioned in different verses of Quran like [6:85](http://tanzil.net/#6:85) and [19:12](http://tanzil.net/#19:12)) and the 4th is [Ibn Muljam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abd-al-Rahman_ibn_Muljam) who murdered [Imam Ali a.s.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali) while Imam was at prayer (Ibn Muljam is called  the most wretched human in different Ahadeeth). But this opinion of Shaykh Tusi and not narrated as a hadith.

---

**Reference:**

http://www.pasokhgoo.ir/node/51811 (the official website of Islamic Questions answering center of [hawzeh Qum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qom_Seminary))

Comment: @Ahmadi, I have not seen explicit naming in any Hadeeth either, but have seen other names as well by different scholars. The ones you counted are among the worst of people, specifically the worst of people have been introduced in a Hadeeth, Namrud and pharaoh are also among them, also Samerie and etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that when you study the history of sahaba and Islam that you will find that the first tyran to be cursed id abu bakr ibn kuhafa, the second tyran to be cursed is Omar ibn khatab, the third tyran to be cursed is Ottman ibn affan and the fourth tyran to be cursed is Moawya ibn abi sofian

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. We rquire answers here to be well elaborated and claims to be referenced by evidences also read [answer].